# GalleryView not shows first image

Tags: android, galleryview

Hi All i have one problem, In the GalleryView not getting the onItemSelected event for first image.below is the image

[image]
when i drag to select first image at index=0, onItemSelected is not calling.
i set `gallery.setSpacing(-IMEGE_WIDTH/2);`
when i remove set spacing it works properly.

Comment: please help me to solve the issue, if somebody want i can post my code too.

Comment: post your activity code + xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3D Carousel View

[link](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/06/a-3d-carousel-view-for-android/#.Uu82Xz2Syi4)